# How to make ArcProgress Bar in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make Arc Progress bar in Flutter.
 Following image is what I want to achieve

[image: Arc Progress Bar]

I am only able to find `CircularProgressIndicator` in the widget catalog for flutter.

I tired the following package
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/percent_indicator

but was not able to achieve the arc progress bar.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `CircularPercentIndicator` like this :

```
         @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        double yourPercentage = 0.5;

        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularPercentIndicator(
              radius: 100.0,
              startAngle: 220,
              percent: 0.775 * yourPercentage,
              animation: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              center: Text("50%"),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Just change the `yourPercentage` variable according to your needs.

**UPDATE (16/05/2019)**

I updated my code (not published yet on pub), but you can use like this way:

In pubspec.yaml

```
 percent_indicator:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_percent_indicator.git
```

Code

```
    CircularPercentIndicator(
                  radius: 120.0,
                  animation: true,
                  animationDuration: 2000,
                  lineWidth: 10.0,
                  percent: 0.5,
                  reverse: true,
                  arcBackgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                  arcType: ArcType.FULL,
                  center: Text(
                    "20 hours",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                  circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  progressColor: Colors.red,
                ),
```

Comment: this is not an arc progress bar it is a complete circular progress bar. I want something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLjUe.png

Comment: @diegoveloper i need to apply a background color as well and if i apply a background color then it appears as a full circular progress bar and why did you multiply 0.775 to precent property

Comment: @diegoveloper thank you very much, for this amazing widget. I have one question. How can you make the ProgressBar start at the top of the circle? 
I tried using the startAngle parameter but it didn't change anything. The bar always starts at the bottom left.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using Flutter CustomPaint class like this.
This will make the same arc as you shared in the image link.
Here, the percentage value can be any from **0** - **0.7**;

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ArcIndicator extends CustomPainter{
        final Color bgColor;
        final Color lineColor;
        final double percent;
        final double width;
       ArcIndicator({
        this.bgColor,
        this.lineColor,
        this.percent,
        this.width
       });
       @override
       void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
         Paint bgLine  = Paint()..color = bgColor
         ..strokeCap=StrokeCap.round
         ..strokeWidth = width
         ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
        Paint completedLine  = Paint()..color = lineColor
         ..strokeCap=StrokeCap.round
         ..strokeWidth = width
         ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    Offset offset = Offset(size.width/2, size.height /2);
    double radius = min(size.width /2 ,size.height/2);
    canvas.drawArc(
        Rect.fromCircle(center: offset,radius: radius),
        2.5,
        2*pi*0.7,
        false,
        bgLine);
      double sweepAngle = 2*pi*percent;
      canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: offset,radius: radius),
      2.5,
      sweepAngle,
      false,
       completedLine);
      }

     @override
     bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
      return true;
     }

     }
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly for my use case as well. Thanks

Comment: The only change I would want is that for 100 percent, I don't want the arch to complete. Something like this

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/753597538447130624/846331691978326016/Screenshot_2021-05-24_at_10.png

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: You can use two `circularProgressIndicator` Widget and one `Text Widget` inside an stack and provide the `value` to `circularProgressIndicator` to make it arc like progress bar.

This is from my project repo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DownloadProgressIndicator extends StatelessWidget {

  DownloadProgressIndicator({
    this.color =Colors.blue,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.black12,
    this.content,
    this.value,
    this.strokeWidth = 4.0,
  });

  final Color color;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Widget content;
  final double value;
  final double strokeWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        backgroundColor != null ? 
        CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(backgroundColor),
          value: 1,
          strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
        ): Container(),
        CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(color),
          value: value,
          strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
        ),
        content != null ? 
        Center(
          child: content,
        ) : Container(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Pass the required progress as `value`. If you need to start the arc at different angle you can put this widget inside a `Transform.rotate` widget. Not exact but it will solve your problem.

Update: after observing your image
You can pass some value to background `circularProgressIndicator` and rotate it to start from bottom.
Let's say your background arc goes from 0 to 75. Now you need to normalise your progress value (eg. value * 75 /100) so it falls feet between 0 to 75  for your foreground progress indicator. rotate foreground arc as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not exactly what the questions specifies. He/She want an output something like this i.stack.imgur.com/mLjUe.png

Comment: Yes I  knew and already mentioned. It is very close what He/She needs just need some modification to rotate and limit the progress to some extent.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/netsmertia/1dd81122a6f7001e96d7b69485834b40 this is what I mean by little modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Arc shape progress bar by using this new package:

https://pub.dev/packages/arc_progress_bar_new

You just call it like this:

```js
  ArcProgressBar(
    percentage: _progressPercentage,
    arcThickness: 5,
    innerPadding: 16,
    animateFromLastPercent: true,
    handleSize: 10,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
    foregroundColor: Colors.black
    )
```